# Пользователи в nginx

Tags: nginx

Можно указать другого пользователя вместо "nobody" ?

К примеру root ? или тот пользователь который обычно заходят в систему ?

Второй вопрос.

И еще, сейчас у меня на конф файле (nginx.conf) этот юзер закомментирован. #user nobody... вот, когда я запускаю nginx, он под каким юзером запускается ?

Comment: 1) Можно, но не нужно; 2) Запустите да посмотрите пользователя в списке процессов, зачем нас спрашивать

Answer (score 4):

Директива `user` говорит о том из-под какого пользователя запускать процесс `Nginx`. Запуска `Nginx` из под `root` - очень плохая идея. Если злоумышленник найдет уязвимость в Nginx, PHP или еще в чем то, что запускает Nginx - то он получит сразу права `root` на всю систему.

Отсюда следствие - запускать `Nginx` хорошо бы из под такого пользователя, который имеет все достаточные права в системе для выполнения им своих задач, но при этом не имеет никаких избыточных прав. Это называется **principle least privelege**.

В общем то, такой пользователь в системе уже есть и это тот самый `nobody`: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/nobody. Поэтому если и прописывать в конфиге какого то другого пользователя - то надо очень хорошо понимать, зачем именно это делается и к чему именно это приведет. Настройки вашего пользователя тестировались не так хорошо, как пользователя `nobody`, и если вы где-то ошиблись - что ж, вам с  этим жить.

> И еще, щас у меня на конф файле (nginx.conf) этот юзер закомментирован. #user nobody... вот, когда я запускаю nginx, он под каким юзером запускается ?

Лучше всего запустить `ps` и проверить это.